# Export Twitter data from Backupify

Tags: export

I signed up for [Backupify](https://www.backupify.com/) and added Twitter to it. I now want to export all my status updates and, although the site says that it's possible to export the data, I can't find that functionality anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some step-by-step instructions here;

http://www.backupify.com/personal/tour

> 1. Click manage next to the service you would like to setup.
> 2. Authorise account
> 3. View archives and export

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't see any link to export the data. At the bottom of that page you sent, there's this "Wait 24 to 48 hours and your initial backup will be ready for download.". That might explain it. Will update on the progress.